# JSON not passing via AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass some JSON via AJAX to a php script, here is my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /**
     * AJAX add to cart
     */
    $( ".single_add_to_cart_button" ).each(function() {

   var el = $(this);

    el.click(function(e) {
            var product_data = $("#jsonVariations").val();

            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).text('Adding to cart');

            // try ajax

            $.ajax({
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: 'add_bv',
                    product_data: product_data,
                },
                dataType: "json",
                //contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                   el.text("Added to cart"); 
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    el.text("Not added to cart"); 
                    //alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });


        return false;

    });

});

});
```

The JSON is valid (tested via jsonlint) and is somehting like this:

```
`[{"variationQty":5,"variationID":"50","variationSize":"2xl","variationColour":"grey"},{"variationQty":10,"variationID":"51","variationSize":"2xl","variationColour":"navy"}]
```

My php script is:

```
$product_data = $_POST['product_data'];
    $product_data = json_decode($product_data, true);

    foreach ($product_data as $product) {
            $product_qty = intval( $product->variationQty );
            $product_id  = 24;
            $product_variation_id = $product->variationID;
            $product_variation = array(
                'colour'    => $product->variationColour,
                'size'      => $product->variationSize,
            );
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $product_qty, $product_variation_id, $product_variation );    
    }
```

I have trialed setting the `$product_data` variable manually to the json and it works perfectly, for some reason it wont pass the `JSON` properly. I have also tried using `JSON` stringify and set the content type, when this happens I get the `AJAX` success function but the php script doesn't seem to execute.

Comment: echo your variable  @rhysclay

Comment: you mean echo $product_data ?

Comment: what you want to pass in JSON

Comment: this is what comes out when I echo [{\"variationQty\":3,\"variationID\":\"44\",\"variationSize\":\"2xl\",\"variationColour\":\"black\"}]0 - this is before json_decode

Comment: Looks like when the json is passed to php all quotes are escaped! That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I ended up stripping slashes with php then it all works perfect!

Comment: @rhysclay by the way where is the error happening? is it happening in your JS or in your PHP script?

Comment: Error was on the php side - just the fact that the JSON had escaped quotes - so strip slashes fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vsogrimen I determined the problem was on the php side. For some reason the JSON object had quotes escaped. I updated my code to strip these slashes and it works perfect. Here is my final code:

```
function prefix_ajax_add_bv() {


$product_data = stripslashes($_POST['product_data']);   
$product_data = json_decode($product_data, false);


foreach ($product_data as $product) {

        $product_qty = intval( $product->variationQty );
        $product_id  = 24;
        $product_variation_id = $product->variationID;
        $product_variation = array(
            'colour'    => $product->variationColour,
            'size'      => $product->variationSize,
        );
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $product_qty, $product_variation_id, $product_variation, array('_my_data','000000000000000000000000000000') );    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the :
 `json_decode($product_data, true)` the return array ,not an object.
 It can be `json_decode($product_data)` or `json_decode($product_data, false)`.
 Hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

is there is only one div with jsonVariations  ID

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake I have not fully understand the Problem.

In `POSTING` `json encoded`  data using ajax, when it reaches to the server it is already converted to a `$_POST[...]` array

your `$_POST` would be:

```
$_POST:
array(
    'action' => 'add_bv',
    'product_data' => array(...the content of product_data...)
);
```

In your case, I think you dont have to decode the posted json data because you just have to use it as is.

```
$product_data = $_POST['product_data']; //Correct, allready an array

$product_data = json_decode($product_data, true); //Not needed
```

Comment: THanks @vsogrimen - still get an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @rhysclay try checking my answer again. Have your tried cheking using print_r() or whatever way to check what is in  $_POST['product_data']; already?